# Android Device Monitor not showing stack trace

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Device Monitor, I'm trying to see **stack trace** in Allocation Tracker, but somehow I managed to lose it and can't get it back.
[See missing box here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOHpJ.jpg)

I've tried Window > Reset perspective, clicking and double clicking on allocations, but the stack trace does not appear. And yes, the update heap (green cylinder) is active.

More info about ADM: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/investigate-ram.html

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a stupid problem:

Using ADM with a large monitor I resized it and going to laptop's smaller screen it just hides the box without the possibility of resizing. So switching back to large screen and resizing there works.